# Ajuda com structs aninhadas em C

Tags: c, ponteiro, lista, struct, lista-encadeada

Estava criando em `C` uma lista e utilizando uma `struct`, após concluir tentei ver o que mudava com uma `struct` aninhada, criei duas `structs` básicas, **uma** recebendo apenas um valor e **outra** recebendo esta primeira e um ponteiro para o mesmo tipo.

Então passei a ter um problema na inserção do dado, nesta minha lista há dois métodos de inserção de dados, um que insere no inicio da lista e outro que insere no fim da lista, ambos funcionavam da mesma forma (com suas particularidades é claro) e percebi que ao inserir um dado ele recebia, mas ao inserir o segundo valor ele alterava o primeiro dado para ficar igual ao segundo e assim por diante sempre alterando todos para o último dado inserido (seria um problema de ponteiro?)

Peguei então o método de inserir no início e alterei a estrutura dele para verificar se conseguia achar uma outra forma de resolver o problema, por fim acabei criando outro problema, segue o link com o código: [Lista em C](https://gist.github.com/brunolpw/c5d061ee57c47dfc3c5bc83874b7953a)

> Observação 1: A opção 3 que insere no final causa o problema que informei.

**Edit:** 24/05/16 19:25

Sobre a função `insere_inicio()`: Ela está funcionando como deveria, ou seja, inserindo valores distintos, e como irei adotar para a função `insere_final()`, no entanto possuo outro problema que não estou sabendo como solucionar, eu gostaria de criar cadeias de **chars** (`strings`) no entanto não estou conseguindo, pois se faço:

```
scanf(" %s", &novo->person.name);
```

Causa um **ERRO** no programa, por isto tive que substituir tudo para `%c`, no entanto gostaria de ler um nome inteiro e não somente uma letra.

Comment: Quanto ao repetir os dados: estás a inserir o ponteiro nas estruturas da lista. Cada estrutura tem um ponteiro com o mesmo endereço. Quando fazes input do novo nome, todos os ponteiros apontam para esse nome. Tens de reservar espaço para cada nome dentro de cada estrutura.

Comment: Certo, então na verdade não estou criando um dado novo, mas sim trabalhando com o mesmo  apenas, seria isso? Mas para resolver isto eu terei que criar uma função para alocar um novo espaço, não sou muito bom com ponteiros ainda, então na verdade eu gostaria de uma ajuda em como proceder com isto.

Comment: A reomendação e'sempre deixar o código junto com a questão - não em serviços externos como pastebin

Comment: @jsbueno não sabia, e como o código é um pouco extenso eu optei por usar um serviço especializado nisto para não "poluir" muito e poder descrever melhor o problema que estava acontecendo, mas já consegui resolver e no mesmo link encontra-se o código funcionando (e suas versões).

Comment: Ok -  a suegstao agora é pesquisar por aí, ou criar novas perguntas - afinal, você fez funcionar mas não entendeu por que: acho que vle a pena uma nova pergunta! :-)

Comment: @jsbueno de fato, eu sei que funciona e entendi superficialmente o que esta acontecendo, no entanto não sei nem ao menos o que seria correto de se perguntar sobre isso, entendo que foi um problema com ponteiros que não estavam sendo atualizados (caso tu veja o código, vai perceber que para solucionar eu optei por "desmembrar" a função aloca() na parte que recebe o valor), mas concordo plenamente com o teu ponto, afinal de contas de que vale ter o código funcionando sem entender o que levou ao erro? Te agradeço pela disposição e pelo auxilio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema solucionado.
Link: [Solução funcionando corretamente](https://gist.github.com/brunolpw/c5d061ee57c47dfc3c5bc83874b7953a)
Optei por utilizar um array de char ao invés de ponteiro (confesso que não sei o que muda entre um e outro nesta utilização).

criei um método chamado "aloca()" que agora esta recebendo a informação da primeira struct e em seguida inserindo de forma correta o dado na segunda struct (principal), revelando que o problema era meramente um ponteiro que estava sendo manipulado diretamente.